# PyCharm error: RuntimeError, Click will abort further execution because Python 3

Tags: python, pycharm

I am learning Flask and first to use PyCharm.

Here is the template code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When i click to run, Here is the Error Info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/jzd/Movies/flask/Three_pyCharm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/__main__.py", line 14, in <module>
    main(as_module=True)
  File "/Users/jzd/Movies/flask/Three_pyCharm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 894, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/Users/jzd/Movies/flask/Three_pyCharm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 557, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jzd/Movies/flask/Three_pyCharm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 676, in main
    _verify_python3_env()
  File "/Users/jzd/Movies/flask/Three_pyCharm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/_unicodefun.py", line 118, in _verify_python3_env
    'for mitigation steps.' + extra)
RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment.  Consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/for mitigation steps.

This system lists a couple of UTF-8 supporting locales that
you can pick from.  The following suitable locales where
discovered: af_ZA.UTF-8, am_ET.UTF-8, be_BY.UTF-8, bg_BG.UTF-8, ca_ES.UTF-8, cs_CZ.UTF-8, da_DK.UTF-8, de_AT.UTF-8, de_CH.UTF-8, de_DE.UTF-8, el_GR.UTF-8, en_AU.UTF-8, en_CA.UTF-8, en_GB.UTF-8, en_IE.UTF-8, en_NZ.UTF-8, en_US.UTF-8, es_ES.UTF-8, et_EE.UTF-8, eu_ES.UTF-8, fi_FI.UTF-8, fr_BE.UTF-8, fr_CA.UTF-8, fr_CH.UTF-8, fr_FR.UTF-8, he_IL.UTF-8, hr_HR.UTF-8, hu_HU.UTF-8, hy_AM.UTF-8, is_IS.UTF-8, it_CH.UTF-8, it_IT.UTF-8, ja_JP.UTF-8, kk_KZ.UTF-8, ko_KR.UTF-8, lt_LT.UTF-8, nl_BE.UTF-8, nl_NL.UTF-8, no_NO.UTF-8, pl_PL.UTF-8, pt_BR.UTF-8, pt_PT.UTF-8, ro_RO.UTF-8, ru_RU.UTF-8, sk_SK.UTF-8, sl_SI.UTF-8, sr_YU.UTF-8, sv_SE.UTF-8, tr_TR.UTF-8, uk_UA.UTF-8, zh_CN.UTF-8, zh_HK.UTF-8, zh_TW.UTF-8
```

I think the line is important.

> RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was
>   configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment.

I find the answer [Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651680/click-will-abort-further-execution-because-python-3-was-configured-to-use-ascii) .

While still not to know how to fix it.

Instructions is very needed, which is easy to follow .

Comment: Have you tried putting `# coding: utf8` at the beginning of your file (first line)?

Comment: Combine with @Nipun Sampath's answer , it works.

Comment: FYI for those wondering "why python3 can error out because of something small like unset locale (i.e. env vars `LANG`, `LC_ALL`)" --> read [PEP 538](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0538/) and the related [PEP 540](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0540/). The error appears to only be an issue for python 3.0 to 3.6 because PEP 538 fixes the issues for python >= 3.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encoding issue with python3 and click package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234393/encoding-issue-with-python3-and-click-package)

Comment: @Trevor Boyd Smith，it has been 3 years. I am not a python programmer any more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Run/debug configurations can be opened from here.

[image]

There you can add the environment variable using this.(click the 3 dot icon next to the environment variables)

[image: step two]

Comment: Not very accurate. Combine with @lonelyloner's answer , it works

Comment: could you please improve the answer?

Comment: please take a review

Comment: well, I was trying to answer in reference to the link you posted in your question. That’s why I didn’t mention all details that were in the link. In any case I’ll update my answer

Comment: I see. Nice of u

Comment: Thank you for improving my answer, you deserve an upvote.  :)